# How to to access state variables or let,const,var variables of one component in other component in React.js?

Tags: reactjs

Suppose I Have to verify OTP...
1. I have written axios .post() request to some route and that route api generates OTP and sends Otp sucessfully to the mobile number, I have used SendOtp package of npm for that.
2. Now I have received that Otp value back in my calling component using callback function of acxios and I have stored in  this.state object.
3. Now i want to verify that otp from user when he types received otp.
4.So for that I have created one React component that consists of single input type and button to verify.
5. How should I approach to this type of routing and variable values passing such that i should be able to verify that OTP...without saving the otp in database

```
 //Front end code:

 axios.post('http://localhost:5000/register      /verifyotp', user)
   .then(profile => {
     console.log(profile.data.OTP)

     this.setState({
       otp: profile.data.OTP
     })
     console.log(this.state.otp)
   })
   .catch(error => {
     console.log(error)
   })

 //Backend code:

 router.route('/verifyotp').post((req, res) => {
   let mobi = req.body.Mobile;
   let ot = "934723"
   sendotp.send(mobi, "NDHome", ot, (error, data) => {
     if (!error) {
       console.log("Sent sucessfully " + data);

       res.json({
         OTP: ot
       }); //verifying otp

     } else {

       console.log(error)

     }
   })
 })
```

Comment: So... how do we share data between components?
- Props Down, Events Up.

Try to avoid is prop drilling (passing the same prop down the tree).

Here are some other useful methods:
Hooks,
Context API,
Redux (IMO, try other strategies first)

Answer (score 0):

For passing of variables between components, look into using redux (https://redux.js.org/introduction/getting-started) or react Context (https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html).

Generally, state variables / const / let / etc.. in a component cannot be passed to another unless it is via props to a child component. For example, in this case assuming 'AnotherComponent' is a modal that overlays the mainComponent during the OTP procedure, then passing over props is possible like this:

```
function mainComponent(props) {
 const [Otp, setOtp] = useState();
 useEffect(() => { // axios stuff here },[]);
 return <AnotherComponent verifyOtp={Otp} />
}
```

Comment: So now How can I pass  this.state.otp  variable to another component and that component will check the entered value of otp from user to the passed otp value from previous component ? How can I request for new route like /verifyotp/confirm and on calling that url the verification page otp on which user will enter the  Otp